# Scraping dynamic elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is my code and it works , But issue it sometime it does not work ? I can say intermmeidate issue and probably because of dynamic elements in in page? what is solution for dynamic elements?

```
def collect_bottom_url(product_string):
    """
    collect_bottom_url:
    This function will accept product name as a argument.
    create a url of product and then collect all the urls given in bottom of page for the product.

    :return: list_of_urls
    """

    url = 'https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=' + product_string
    # download the main webpage of product
    webpage = requests.get(url)

    # Store the main URL of Product in a list
    list_of_urls = list()
    list_of_urls.append(url)

    # Create a web page of downloaded page using lxml parser
    my_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.text, "lxml")

    # find_all class = pagnLink in web page
    urls_at_bottom = my_soup.find_all(class_='pagnLink')

    empty_list = list()
    for b_url in urls_at_bottom:
        empty_list.append(b_url.find('a')['href'])

    for item in empty_list:
        item = "https://www.amazon.in/" + item
        list_of_urls.append(item)
    print(list_of_urls)


collect_bottom_url('book')
```

Here is output 1 which is fine :

```
['https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=book', 'https://www.amazon.in//book/s?ie=UTF8&page=2&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abook', 'https://www.amazon.in//book/s?ie=UTF8&page=3&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abook']
```

Here is output 2 which is incorrect :

```
['https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=book']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its not dynamic but it ask captcha because you use default user-agent, change it.

```
headers= {"User-Agent" : 'Mozilla/5.0.............'}
def collect_bottom_url(product_string):
    .....
    webpage = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

for dynamic page use [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=selenium+python).

Comment: Can you please explain me what you did in these lines?headers= {"User-Agent" : 'Mozilla/5.0.............'} what does it means?

Comment: it will be used as header to be used in `requests`